# The spur on my boot has been tied up with your dress

Tags: grammar

'What's happened?Have I hurt you,friend?'a man asked.
'no,' said Bathsheba ,trying to pull her skirt away.
'Ah! you are a lady !The spur on my boot ***has got tied up*** with your dress.'

Far from the madding crowd by Thomas Hardy.

what kind of structure is that ?

Does it mean ;

'Ah! you are a lady !The spur on my boot has been tied up with your dress.' ?
an other way of making passive voice with ''get'' ?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "has got tied up with your dress" means the same as "has become tangled in your dress", which is something that happened by accident. I don't think it is a passive structure; rather, "tied up" is an adjective meaning the same as "tangled".

"Has been tied up with", can't be substituted there with the same meaning.

Comment: ''She has got me twisted'' is the story of Pratheeksha Chauan and Abhinay Krishan who were a happy couple in a long distance relationship.

in this context, does it mean;

''she has become me twisted'' ?

Comment: @ullas84 No. It's you that has become twisted, so you can't say "She has become..." That might passivize as "I have been twisted (by her), or, if "twisted" is seen as an adjective, "I was made twisted by her." That use isn't the same as the OP example because it has an agent "she", and an object "me".